# How to convert a folder to a jar file (MAC)?

Tags: eclipse, jar, directory

I need to add a jar file to my Eclipse project, but all I've got is the folder with the necessary Java files. 
I found a way to convert from folder to jar: compress the folder and change the extension to .jar. But when I add it to my project, the jar file seems to be empty (no Java files).

Is there a better way to obtain a jar file or to fix this problem?

Comment: How did you "compress the folder"? By Java files do you mean .class files or .java source files? You need to add a jar to solve what problem?

Comment: I zipped it. 
.java files, generated from .proto files.
It needs a lot of methods from com.google.protobuf.

Comment: I understand what you did, I'm asking *how*.

Answer (score 1):

That's absolutely NOT the way to do it.
You can create a jar from a project in workspace in this way:

> In the Package Explorer, you can optionally pre-select one or more
>   Java elements to export.
>
> Either from the context menu or from the menu bar's File menu, select
>   Export.
>
> Expand the Java node and select JAR file. Click Next.
>
> In the JAR File Specification page, select the resources that you want
>   to export in the Select the resources to export field.
>
> Select the appropriate checkbox to specify whether you want to Export
>   generated class files and resources or Export Java source files and
>   resources. Note: Selected resources are exported in both cases.
>
> In the Select the export destination field, either type or click
>   Browse to select a location for the JAR file.
>
> Select or clear the Compress the contents of the JAR file checkbox.
>
> Select or clear the Overwrite existing files without warning checkbox.
>   If you clear this checkbox, then you will be prompted to confirm the
>   replacement of each file that will be overwritten. Note: The overwrite
>   option is applied when writing the JAR file, the JAR description, and
>   the manifest file.
>
> You have two options: Click Finish to create the JAR file immediately.
>   Click Next to use the JAR Packaging Options page to set advanced
>   options, create a JAR description, or change the default manifest.

Comment: How to do it if the folder is NOT a project/or related to java? Can I create a jar out of any kind of folder? I'm trying to do on mac but finding it hard.